# What is acmsoda running on port 6969?

Tags: bittorrent

When I scanned a web application for open ports using built in nmap command, it showed me that there is a closed port 6969 in which a service is running named acmsoda. When I did some googling on this, I found that it is the standard port run by BitTorrent client. What is actually this service acmsoda do? Is that a security threat to open this port?

Comment: Please dont post same questions, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68622/what-is-acmsoda-running-on-port-6969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

6969 is the default port for some bittorrent clients and acmsoda is the service name which is using that port.

& acmsoda is a seeding service from Bit Torrent clients.

No its not a security threat and its a Bandwidth matter , you know over seeding will.

Answer (score 1):

For security, it is important to know which process opens which port.

Run these commands to get information about processes and their ports:

```
sudo netstat -ltup
sudo lsof -i
```

6969 is the default port for the most famous bittorrent tracker software.

http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker/

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=6969), it can be a backdoor for attackers.

Backdoor assassin trojans may open the port 6969 to listen for the attacker. These malwares may enter the system through any infected likes applications or torrents.

Answer (score 0):

In spain we have a fedicom server that listens to this port
Fedicom is a protocol that is used to send orders between pharmacy